# Does the sum of squares of Hermitian matrices/operators have positive eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

Let us have the operator $Q=\sum_iA_i^2$ where each $A_i$ is a Hermitian operator. I have found a statement saying that $Q$ must have positive eigenvalues. How can one show this?

I think it has to do with the fact that Hermitian operators have real eigenvalues and so when we square them (something which we can get from the action of $A_i$ to one of its eigenfuctions/eigenvectors) we get something positive. But, even with this information, I cannot figure a way to prove that $Q$ has positive eigenvalues.

Comment: Positive? Not true. $0$ is Hermitian, and $0^2=0$ doesn't have positive eigenvalues. If you want non-negative, then observe that $(Qx,x)=\sum_i(Ax,Ax)=\sum_i\|Ax\|^2\geq0$. Then, If $x$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $\lambda$, it follows that $\lambda\|x\|^2=(Qx,x)$ is a sum of squares. Therefore, $\lambda\geq0$.

Comment: @spiralstotheleft Why is $(Qx,x)=\sum_i (Ax,Ax)$?

Comment: $(Qx,x)=(\sum_iA_i^2x,x)=\sum_i(A_i^2x,x)=\sum_i(A_ix,A_ix)$. Add all missing subscripted $i$'s above.

Comment: @spiralstotheleft Thanks!

Comment: In english, a positive number $a$ satisfies $a>0$. cf. the @spiralstotheleft 's post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know that the squares of Hermitian operators are positive; the question concerns their sums. Well, the individual summands $A_i^2$ have the property that $\langle v,A_i^2v\rangle\geq0$ for all vectors $v$. Sum over $i$ and use the fact that the inner product is linear in each factor to get $\langle v,(\sum_iA_i^2)v\rangle\geq0$ for all $v$. In paarticular, if $v$ is an eigenvector of $\sum_iA_i^2$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $\langle v,\lambda v\rangle\geq0$ and therefore $\lambda\geq0$.

Comment: The square of a hermitian operator is non-negative.

Comment: @loupblanc It seems to be fairly common to use "positive" (for Hermitian operators) to mean that the spectrum lies in $[0,\infty)$ and to use "strictly positive" or "positive definite" to mean that the spectrum lies in $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: A few examples of books where "positive" allows zero to be in the spectrum: Nielsen & Chuang "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information". Berberian "Introduction to Hilbert Space". Arveson "An Invitation to C^* Algebras".

Comment: I wrote my comment a little provocatively; in english, for a real number, we use the notations "non-negative " and "positive"  -in french, we say "positive or zero" and "strictly positive"-; for  a hermitian matrix, as you, I met the notations "positive definite" and "positive"  -in french, the convention is the same! I wonder if it is (or it is not) Bourbaki who imposed this last notation everywhere-.

Answer (score 2):

Let's call an operator $T$ positive if $T=T^*$ and $\sigma(T)\subset\mathbb R_{\geq0}$.  Then it's not too difficult to show the following:

> Let $T$ be a self-adjoint operator.  Then the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $T$ is positive,
> 2. $\|\lambda-T\|\leq \lambda$ for all $\lambda\geq \|T\|$,
> 3. $\|\lambda-T\|\leq\lambda$ for some $\lambda\geq \|T\|$.

Using this, one can show that if $T_1$ and $T_2$ are positive, then $T_1+T_2$ is positive.  Finally, as you've noted, if $T$ is self-adjoint, then $T^2$ is positive.

Thus if $T_1,\ldots, T_n$ are self-adjoint, then $T_1^2,\ldots,T_n^2$ are positive, hence $\sum_kT_k^2$ is positive, and the result follows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have accepted the other answer because it is slightly easier for me to grasp

Comment: I understand, that explanation is probably better for your purposes.  My answer is tailored to work in a more abstract setting.

Comment: Sure, your answers will probably serve mathematicians better in the long run! Thanks again!

Comment: $T^2$ is non-negative.

Comment: @loupblanc That may be your standard, but even if you choose to reserve the word positive for something else, I make explicit what the term means in my answer at the beginning.

Comment: You are right, I did not read the first line! See also my comment above, about the Andreas Blass 's answer.